# Dynamic Filter in Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample data frame below :

```
Name   Rate    Period
Ann     98     201403
Ann     97     201402
Ann     99     201401
Ann     94     201312
Ann     96     201311
Ann     92     201310
Ann     93     201309
Ben     92     201403
Ben     94     201402
Ben     96     201401
Ben     93     201312
Ben     99     201311
Ben     97     201310
Ben     92     201309
```

How can I filter the data frame to get only the data for last 6 months?

Desired output:

```
Name   Rate    Period
Ann     98     201403
Ann     97     201402
Ann     99     201401
Ann     94     201312
Ann     96     201311
Ann     92     201310
Ben     92     201403
Ben     94     201402
Ben     96     201401
Ben     93     201312
Ben     99     201311
Ben     97     201310
```

I can do it by subsetting and providing the filters like

```
dataset= subset(dataset, Period %in% ('201403','201402','201401','201312','201311','201310'))
```

But since the period will be dynamic as time passes by, is there any way for me to get this dynamically like `Period >= date - 6`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using `zoo`, `yearmon` is the class you need:

```
library(zoo)
df_index <- as.yearmon(as.character(df$Period), format="%Y%m")
df[df_index > max(df_index) - 1/2, ]

   Name Rate Period
1   Ann   98 201403
2   Ann   97 201402
3   Ann   99 201401
4   Ann   94 201312
5   Ann   96 201311
6   Ann   92 201310
8   Ben   92 201403
9   Ben   94 201402
10  Ben   96 201401
11  Ben   93 201312
12  Ben   99 201311
13  Ben   97 201310
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the `Period` column to `factor` and subset by the first six.

```
dataset[dataset$Period %in% as.factor(dataset$Period)[1:6], ]
## equivalent to
subset(dataset, Period %in% as.factor(Period)[1:6])

##    Name Rate Period
## 1   Ann   98 201403
## 2   Ann   97 201402
## 3   Ann   99 201401
## 4   Ann   94 201312
## 5   Ann   96 201311
## 6   Ann   92 201310
## 8   Ben   92 201403
## 9   Ben   94 201402
## 10  Ben   96 201401
## 11  Ben   93 201312
## 12  Ben   99 201311
## 13  Ben   97 201310
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It does not require any extra packages. It makes a unique list of periods, sorts in ascending order, and selects the last 6. See the help of `tail`.

```
dataset <- subset(dataset, Period %in% tail(sort(unique(Period))))
```

Please note. This code selects the last six months **observed in data**. Probably this solution does not fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)

df$date <- ymd(paste0(df$Period, "01"))

df[max(df$date) - months(6) < df$date, ]

#    Name Rate Period       date
# 1   Ann   98 201403 2014-03-01
# 2   Ann   97 201402 2014-02-01
# 3   Ann   99 201401 2014-01-01
# 4   Ann   94 201312 2013-12-01
# 5   Ann   96 201311 2013-11-01
# 6   Ann   92 201310 2013-10-01
# 8   Ben   92 201403 2014-03-01
# 9   Ben   94 201402 2014-02-01
# 10  Ben   96 201401 2014-01-01
# 11  Ben   93 201312 2013-12-01
# 12  Ben   99 201311 2013-11-01
# 13  Ben   97 201310 2013-10-01
```